# Bread Crumb Pattern Implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am developing an asp.net mvc 2.0 application in which I want to implement bread crumb pattern but I don't know how to implement it in asp.net. By browsing different sites I come to know about MVCSiteMap Provider but I don't know how to use it and how I can implement bread crumb in asp.net mvc 2.0 using mvcsitemap. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MvcSiteMapProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki) is, as the name implies, an ASP.NET MVC SiteMapProvider implementation for the ASP.NET MVC framework. Targeted at ASP.NET MVC 2, it provides sitemap XML functionality and interoperability with the classic ASP.NET sitemap controls, like the SiteMapPath control for rendering breadcrumbs and the Menu control.

**Creating a first sitemap**

The following is a simple sitemap XML file that can be used with the MvcSiteMapProvider:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<mvcSiteMap xmlns="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-3.0" enableLocalization="true"> 
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index" changeFrequency="Always" updatePriority="Normal"> 
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Browse Store" controller="Store" action="Index" /> 
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Checkout" controller="Checkout" /> 
  </mvcSiteMapNode> 
</mvcSiteMap>
```

**Defining sitemap nodes in code**

In some cases, defining a sitemap node in code is more convenient than defining it in a sitemap xml file. To do this, decorate an action method with the MvcSiteMapNodeAttribute attribute. For example:

```
// GET: /Checkout/Complete 
[MvcSiteMapNodeAttribute(Title = "Checkout complete", ParentKey = "Checkout")] 
public ActionResult Complete(int id) 
{ 
    // ... 
}
```

[MvcSiteMapProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki)

[MVC Sitemap Provider tutorial and examples](http://edspencer.me.uk/2011/02/10/mvc-sitemap-provider-tutorial/)

[MVC Sitemap Provider tutorial 2 – Breadcrumbs](http://edspencer.me.uk/2011/09/20/mvc-sitemap-provider-tutorial-2-breadcrumbs/)

Comment: But dear all the forums are using razor syntax and I am unable to use razor syntax in mvc 2.0 :(